# Bind an event with onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

I use the following code to prompt a message if the user close the page :

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    e = e ? e : window.event;
    if(e) { 
        e.returnValue = ''; 
    }
    return '';
}
```

I would like to avoid the prompt this message shows when a user clicks a special link (let say `id="myid"`) on the page. Is it possible? I tried like this:

```
var source = e.target || e.srcElement;
console.log(source);
```

But `source` is `null`, is it possible to bind the event and to check it with `onbeforeunload`?

and what are the "e" attributes ? how I can look into this "object" ? Any idea ?

Comment: you unbind the event if the click is triggered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unbind the event if the link is clicked and then redirect

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```